# nmcli won't let me remove DNS entry from /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: centos, dns, networkmanager, nmcli

Centos 7.5, nmcli version 1.20.2

Whenever I try to remove entries from /etc/resolv.conf I get the following errors.

```
[root@client ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
search home
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 192.168.1.1
[root@client ~]# nmcli connection modify enp0s3 -ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8
Error: failed to remove a value from ipv4.dns: the property doesn't contain DNS server '8.8.8.8'.
[root@client ~]# nmcli device show enp0s3 
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s3
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         08:00:27:FA:EE:AC
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     enp0s3
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.8/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8
IP4.DNS[2]:                             192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::18c:3f05:dcaf:65fd/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
[root@client ~]# systemctl is-active NetworkManager
active
```

Answer (score 2):

I've done this today, and it works on a RHEL8 box:

```
nmcli con mod "System eth0" ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"
nmcli con mod "System eth0" ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
nmcli con mod "System eth0" ipv6.dns "2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844"
nmcli con mod "System eth0" ipv6.ignore-auto-dns yes
nmcli con up id "System eth0"
```

Note this is using the Google DNS IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. I did not have to modify `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have gotten it to work by adding the `dns=none` to the `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file under the [main] section and then restarting `NetworkManager`

I can then add DNS entries to the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg*` files like so

```
DNS1=192.168.1.175
DNS2=192.168.1.176
```

Or directly to `/etc/resolv.conf` using vim

Answer (score 0):

Those values in capital letters are calculated - fetched from the DHCP if not provided manually. Have a look at the entry `ipv4.dns`. I bet yours is empty.

If you wish - add them yourself by setting the DNS entries:

```
nmcli connection modify enp0s3 ipv4.dns 192.168.1.1
nmcli connection down enp0s3
nmcli connection up enp0s3
```

EDIT: Indeed I made a typo here. Have look above.

Comment: Am I not doing that? I get the error seen above

Comment: Right. I've copied the line but did not make the very basic editing. My bad.